# select on last value by date in another table

Tags: mysql, date, join, max

I am trying to select data from a table of annual data (`Companies_Annual`) and convert the values into another currency based on the prevailing exchange rates at their fiscal year end which are stored in a second table containing daily exchange rates (`FX_daily`).  A complicating factor however is that an exchange rate value may not be available for some historic fiscal year ends I need to select on from `Companies_Annual`, while future annual data will need to be converted at the last prevailing exchange rate.

My question is, how can I select the last available `fx_rate` from the `FX_daily` table that relates to the `Year` in the `CA` table and apply this to convert the `Value` field in the `CA` table?  I have tried to join `CA.year` on `FX.Date` and use the `MAX()` function to get the last `fx_rate` for each of the `CA.Year`, but my syntax is clearly wrong.  Can anyone help me with this?

The table structures are broadly:

```
CA table
Year        ticker  Value       
2012-12-31  xyz     2,000       
2013-12-31  xyz     2,100       
2014-12-31  xyz     2,200       
2015-12-31  xyz     2,300       
2016-12-31  xyz     2,400       

FX_daily table 
Date        fx_code  fx_rate
2000-12-25  £:$         1.45
2000-05-26  £:$         1.45
2000-05-27  £:$         1.45
……  etc
2014-02-04  £:$         1.67
2014-02-05  £:$         1.65
2014-02-06  £:$         1.67
2014-02-07  £:$         1.66
```

I have attempted to combine simple select to get `Year` data from from the CA table

```
SELECT ca.year
FROM companies_annual ca
WHERE ca.ticker ='xyz' 
AND ca.year >=2013-12-31 
ORDER BY ca.year LIMIT 4
```

Which gives me the year end dates OK

```
year
2012-12-31
2013-12-31
2014-12-31
2015-12-31
```

and used the `Max()` function to get the last `fx_rate` and `date`,

```
SELECT max(date),fx_code,fx_rate 
FROM fx_daily
WHERE date <='2016-12-31'
AND fx_code ='$:£' 
ORDER BY date LIMIT 6
```

Which gets me the last rate, but for only 1 year

```
max(date)   fx_code   fx_rate
2014-03-05  $:£         1.618
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `GROUP BY` to your query on `fx_code` and `fx_rate` values.

**Example**:

```
SELECT 
  max(date) mx_date,fx_code,fx_rate 
FROM fx_daily
WHERE 
  date <='2016-12-31' AND fx_code ='$:£' 
GROUP BY 
  fx_code, fx_rate
ORDER BY date LIMIT 6
```

Comment: Thanks Ravinder, your code provides the last 6 days fx_rate from the fx_daily table but not the fx_rates for each of the last 6 year end dates from the Companies_Annual (CA) table which is what I was after.

Comment: Can anyone help to finish this one off?